# Проверка $_GET

Tags: php, get

Как сделать проверку GET, нужно чтобы кроме цифр в диапазоне 1,20 не проходили, и фильтровать от инъекций, так число будет заносится в бд

Answer (score 4):

Не особо люблю регулярки, да и с условием проще вам будет для понимания, все просто как 2x2 :)

```
if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] <= 20 && $_GET['id'] >= 1) {
    echo 'okay';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

тут проверяем являеется ли id числом, ставим в условие что для true id должен быть меньше или равнятся 20 и больше или равнятся 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (in_array($_GET['num'], range(1,20))) echo "OK";
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно.

```
$num = $_GET['num'];
if ( $num >= 1 && $num <= 20 ) {
  echo true;
} else {
  echo false;
}
```

Вообще есть много вариантов, это один из них.

---

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,22}$/",$book)
```

`{1,22}` — указывает на длину чисел, а не на их диапазон.

Answer (score 0):

Вы будете (не)приятно удивлены:

```
$num='14"ddfdfd';

if($num>=1 && $num<=20) echo 'true';
```

:)))

Например можно сделать так:

```
$num=intval($num)%21;
if($num){
 /*все ок*/}
```

Comment: Просто не надо забывать о **is_numeric()**. А вот %21 - это уже клиника

Comment: почему "клиника" ?

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что вопрос из прошлого, но у меня есть свое решение. Я использую ДВЕ функции, потому что Я так использую в своем коде. И диапазоны значений у меня разные. И проверять нужно отдельно длину числа и длину строк. Поэтому у меня две функции.

Я подправил код именно под этот конкретный вопрос.

```
function is_numb($numb) {
  if (!preg_match('#^[1-9]+[0-9]*$#', $numb) or ! cl($numb, 1, 2) or $numb > 20) {
  return(false);
  } else {
  return(true);
  }
}


function cl($str, $min, $max) {
//проверяется длина переменной
  if (mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8') < $min or mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8') > $max) {
  return(FALSE);
  } else {
  return(TRUE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ну и как вариант жёсткое сравнение.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['num']))
    if(($_GET['num'] >== 0) && ($_GET['num'] <== 20))
echo 'Ok';
```

Comment: всегда будет FALSE , потому что при тренарном сравнении проверяется также и тип переменной. А в `$_GET` всегда `string` Или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score -3):

Я думаю, Вам надо использовать и почитать про регулярные выражения. Я сам их плохо знаю, но вроде в данном случае надо применить такое: [1-20].

Функции [preg_match](http://www.php.su/functions/?preg-match)

Comment: это сам знаю, только регулярку не могу найти, а сам их плохо понимаю т.к не учил

Comment: {1,22} это не диапозон в том смысле что имел ввиду ТС, эти цифры означают что в $book может быть от 1 и до 22 цифр.